# Ansible Inventory file precedence

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I've been reading through the `vars` precedence within Ansible and I'm not sure if the behavior I'm getting is by design or not. Here is my Ansible inventory;

```
---

all:
  children:
    we:
      children:
        workers:
          hosts:
            worker-we-vm1:
              order: 1
            worker-ew-vm2:
              order: 2
          vars:
            size: "Standard_B2s"
        controllers:
          hosts:
            controller-we-vm:
              order: 1
          vars:
            size: "Standard_B1s"
      vars:
        ip_prefix: "10.60"
    scus:
      children:
        workers:
          hosts:
            worker-scus-vm1:
              order: 1
            worker-scus-vm2:
              order: 2
          vars:
            size: "Standard_B2s"
      vars:
        ip_prefix: "10.61"
  vars:
    azure_profile: "test"
```

Now what I'd expect is that the `we` VMs (e.g. `worker-we-vm1`) would have `ip_prefix` set to `10.60` and the `scus` VMs (e.g. `worker-scus-vm1`) would have `ip_prefix` set to `10.61` when accessing `hostvars`. But they're not, all of the VMs have `ip_prefix` set to `10.60`.

Can anyone please help with understanding why the `vars` precedence isn't working as expected? I've read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html and it seems to contradict itself on how parent and same-level variables are handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible host group namespace is flat, not hierarchical, so there is only a single `workers` group in your example.

As you define the same variable for that group twice, only the last value is preserved.

Split your `workers` group, for example, to `workers_we` and `workers_scus` (and use host patterns if that was the reason for the definition).

Comment: Thanks, I've just modified it as you suggested and I'm still getting the same issue unfortunately. As the variables are set at the `scus`/`we` group level and not the `workers`/`controllers` group level would it have any effect anyway?

Comment: So you are doing something different. If you take the inventory you posted and rename `workers` in one place, the result does change.　I'm not sure what you ask about in the second part - you define the variable value for `we` and expect it not to be inherited by `workers` or `controllers`? How would it make sense?

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I'd been an idiot! Ta very much